# Dynamic code in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, compilation

In our ASP.NET Application, we have a feature that allows the use to write scripts in C# or VB.NET code. These scripts are stored in the database and compiled at specified intervals, executing the code that is stored in these scripts.

This works as long as the user is writing basic .NET code. Ofcourse our customers now request that they're able to reference their own DLLs to allow the execution of specific code. This is acceptable for us and we're creating a solution for this. However there is a specific scenario that we wish to avoid at all times:

**The application is not allowed to copy the referenced DLL files into the BIN folder of the ASP.NET side, as this restarts the application and this is not supported/allowed**

I've been playing around with the CompilerOptions class and I've noticed that you're able to set your referenced libraries there. From the information I could find on the MSDN site:

- You can set a *library path* using the following: CompilerOptions =
  ""/libpath:<path>""
- You can add a reference like so:
  CompilerOptions.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("assembly name")
- You can
  add a reference like so:
  CompilerOptions.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("full path to assembly")

In our scripts we also have the following mechanism in place; users can define a References region in their code that contains paths to various custom DLLs needed to execute the script. An Example script could look like this:

```
#region References
/*
 * C:\Program Files\MailBee\MailBee.Net.dll
 * C:\Program Files\CustomApp\Custom.dll
 * System.IO.dll
/*
#endregion

namespace custom.script.space {
   class CustomScript : Script {
     [EntryPoint]
     public voic run()
     { // do stuff }
   }
}
```

This would reference the System.IO assembly and the two custom DLLs specified. However with the current implementation, we would copy the custom DLLs to the GAC and then just add their name as reference to the compiler.

Would it be possible to disable the copy of the DLL and use full paths to these dlls to be referenced, without having them copied to the GAC/bin folder of the application? And would it be possible to use the CompilerOptions to set the libpath and let all references point to this?

The reason why we don't want to copy the Dlls and restart the applications, is because we have multi-instance applications, several customers on a single instance, and we can't simply restart an application.

I hope the question is clear on what I'm trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I'm currently using seems to be working fine without me having the specify specific assemblies. The code that compiles the script and loads all dynamic references looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the dynamic references.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
    /// <param name="assemblyDllPath">The assembly DLL path.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string[] GetDynamicReferences(string source, string assemblyDllPath)
    {
        var filenames = new List<string>();

        const string startRegion = "#region References";
        const string endRegion = "#endregion";
        const string commentStart = "/*";
        const string commentEnd = "*/";
        const string commentLine = "//";
        const string libpath = "/libpath";
        var sourceReader = new StringReader(source);
        string currentLine;
        bool inReferenceRegion = false;
        bool inReferenceCommentRegion = false;

        // Loop over the lines in the script and check each line individually.
        while ((currentLine = sourceReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Strip the current line of all trailing spaces.
            currentLine = currentLine.Trim();

            // Check if we're entering the region 'References'.
            if (currentLine.StartsWith(startRegion))
            {
                inReferenceRegion = true;   // We're entering the region, set the flag.
                continue;                   // Skip to the next line.
            }

            // Check if we're exiting the region 'References'. If so, stop the for loop.
            if (currentLine.StartsWith(endRegion)) break;

            // If we're processing a line that's not in the 'References' region, then skip the line
            // as we're only interested in the lines from that region.
            if (!inReferenceRegion) continue;

            // Check if we're entering the comments section, because the entire region is actually
            // a big comment block, starting with /*
            if (currentLine.StartsWith(commentStart))
            {
                inReferenceCommentRegion = true;    // We're entering the comment block.
                continue;                           // Skip to the next line.
            }

            // Check if we're leaving the comments section, because then we're almost done parsing
            // the entire comment block.
            if (currentLine.EndsWith(commentEnd))
            {
                inReferenceCommentRegion = false;   // Leaving the comment block.
                continue;                           // Skip to the next line.
            }

            // If the line we're processing starts with a comment '//', then skip the line because it's
            // not to be processed anymore by us, just as if it was placed in comment in real code.
            // If the line contains a double slash, strip one of the slashes from it and parse the data.
            if (currentLine.Contains(commentLine))
            {
                if (currentLine.StartsWith(commentLine)) continue;
                currentLine = currentLine.Substring(0, currentLine.IndexOf(commentLine) - 1);
            }

            // If we're dealing with a line that's not inside the reference comment section, skip it
            // because we're only interested in the lines inside the comment region section of the script.
            if (!inReferenceCommentRegion) continue;

            // Trim the current line of all trailing spaces, the line should represent either the fullpath
            // to a DLL, the librarypath option, or the relative path of a DLL.
            string line = currentLine.Trim();

            // If the line starts with the library option, then we need to extract this information, and store it
            // inside the local varialbe that holds the libpath.
            if (line.Equals(libpath))
            {
                string dataHomeFolder = Api2.Factory.CreateApi().Parameters.Read(343).Value;
                string companyName = Api2.Factory.CreateApi().Parameters.Read(113).Value;
                _libraryPath = Path.Combine(dataHomeFolder, companyName, "libraries");
            }

            // If the line is not an absolute path to the referenced DLL, then we need to assume that the DLL resides
            // in the library path. We'll build up the full path using the library path, if the path has been set.
            if (!Path.IsPathRooted(line) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_libraryPath))
                line = Path.Combine(_libraryPath, line);                

            // If the file exists, then we'll add it as reference to the collection to be used by the compiler.
            // We will not copy the file however in the bin folder of the application.
            var fio = new FileInfo(line);
            if (fio.Exists && !filenames.Contains(line)) filenames.Add(line);
        }

        // Return the entire collection of libraries.
        return filenames.ToArray();
    }
```

This loads all the dynamic references that I have defined inside the region block into the compiler. Using the Compile class from C#.NET, I'm able to compile my source code from the script and link to external DLLS.

This code performs the compilation:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>This function performs the compile operation and return the compiled assembly.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source code of the script to compile.</param>
    /// <param name="libs">A collection of additional libraries to compile the script.</param>
    /// <returns>The compiled assembly.</returns>
    internal Assembly Compile(string source, List<string> libs)
    {
        var libraries = new List<string>(libs);
        CodeDomProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
        var compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
                                 {
                                     CompilerOptions = "/target:library /optimize",
                                     GenerateExecutable = false,
                                     GenerateInMemory = true,
                                     IncludeDebugInformation = true,
                                     TreatWarningsAsErrors = false
                                 };
        string assemblyDllPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath);

        // Load all the required assemblies depending on the api implementation.
        LoadAssemblies(compilerParams, source, assemblyDllPath, libraries);

        var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TF-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper());

        // replace resx-files from provided libraries with compatible dll's
        var resxs = libraries.FindAll(lb => lb.EndsWith(".resx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        var tmpFiles = new List<string>();
        if (resxs.Count > 0)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            foreach (var resx in resxs)
            {
                // Get the resources filename
                var resourceFilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(resx);
                var filename = Path.Combine(path, resourceFilename + ".resources");
                File.Delete(filename);
                tmpFiles.Add(filename);

                // Create a ResXResourceReader for the file items.resx.
                Stream stream = File.Open(resx, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                var rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(stream);

                // Create a ResXResourceReader for the file items.resources.
                IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter(filename);

                // Iterate through the resources and add resources to the resource writer.
                IDictionary dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
                {
                    var k = d.Key.ToString();
                    var v = d.Value.ToString();

                    dictionary.Add(k, v);
                    writer.AddResource(k, v);
                }

                // Close the reader.
                rsxr.Close();
                stream.Close();
                writer.Close();

                compilerParams.EmbeddedResources.Add(filename);

                string[] errors;
                var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(); // c#-code compiler
                var cu = StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.Create(dictionary, resourceFilename ?? string.Empty, "", provider, false, out errors);

                var options = new CodeGeneratorOptions
                                  {
                                      BracingStyle = "C",
                                      BlankLinesBetweenMembers = false,
                                      IndentString = "\t"
                                  };

                var tw = new StringWriter();
                provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(cu, tw, options);
                var libCode = tw.ToString();
                tw.Close();
                if (!libraries.Contains(libCode))
                    libraries.Add(libCode);
            }
            libraries.RemoveAll(lb => lb.EndsWith(".resx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }

        // actually compile the code
        CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, new List<string>(libraries) { source }.ToArray());

        // remove the temporary files
        foreach (var file in tmpFiles)
            File.Delete(file);

        // remove the resource directory
        if(Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.Delete(path);

        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder("Compilation error :\n\t");
            foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                sb.AppendLine("\t" + error.ErrorText);
            throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
        }

        //get a hold of the actual assembly that was generated
        Assembly generatedAssembly = results.CompiledAssembly;

        // move to some app startup place (this only needs to be set once)
        if (!API.Factory.IsAPIImplementationTypeSet)
        { API.Factory.SetAPIImplementation(Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyDllPath + "\\TenForce.Execution.API.Implementation.dll").GetType("TenForce.Execution.API.Implementation.API")); }

        // Set the implementation type for the API2 as well. This should only be set once.
        if (!Api2.Factory.ImplementationSet)
        { Api2.Factory.SetImplementation(Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyDllPath + "\\TenForce.Execution.Api2.Implementation.dll").GetType("TenForce.Execution.Api2.Implementation.Api")); }

        return generatedAssembly;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to listen to the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event and then go from there loading the assembly yourselves. More information is at - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx

and

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

Comment: Usefull information but not what I'm looking for, or at least not what I needed. Apparently it's sufficient to give the full path in my compile engine and it will be loaded. And I think it's because I'm loading into a new ApplicationDomain and compiling the DLL in memory that I don't require this.

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack blogged about some not very well known extensibility hooks in ASP.NET 4.0. One of them is an event, fired very early in the app lifecycle, where you can register build providers and add assembly references. Maybe you can use that to dynamically add references, but still the application needs to be restarted. Here's the blog post with more information:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx